# How do you use _Generic with structs that are typedef-ed in C?

Tags: c, generics, struct, overloading

I'm new to C and currently exploring the concept of function overloading via the use of _Generic in C11.

In [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44633838/7489488), @Lundin provides the following code snippet, which I've gotten running with no issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func_int (int x) { printf("%d\n", x); }
void func_char (char ch) { printf("%c\n", ch); }

#define func(param)          \
  _Generic((param),          \
    int:  func_int(param),   \
    char: func_char(param)); \

int main() 
{
  func(1);
  func((char){'A'});
}
```

@Lundin also mentioned the following:

> A much better way would be to make a function interface with a single
> struct parameter, which can be adapted to contain all the necessary
> parameters. With such an interface you can use the above simple method
> based on _Generic. Type safe and maintainable.

So I decided to extend the above example to `structs` to see it in action.

Below is my attempt:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct args_int Args_int;
typedef struct args_char Args_char;

void func_int(Args_int args);
void func_char(Args_char args);

struct args_int {
    int val;
};
struct args_char {
    char val;
};

#define func(param)\
    _Generic((param),\
        Args_int: func_int(param),\
        Args_char: func_char(param));


void func_int (Args_int args) {
    printf("%d\n", args.val);
}

void func_char (Args_char args) {
    printf("%c\n", args.val);
}

int main(void) {
    Args_char args = {0};
    args.val = 'A';
    func(args);
}
```

However, unfortunately, I get the following compilation error, which complains that I've passed in an `Args_char` when the compiler is expecting an `Args_int`. Clearly, my intent is to pass an `Args_char` and my expectation is for `func_char` to be called as a result.

```
struct_args_by_val_executable.c:35:10: error: passing 'Args_char' (aka 'struct args_char') to parameter of incompatible type 'Args_int' (aka 'struct args_int')
    func(args);
         ^~~~
struct_args_by_val_executable.c:20:28: note: expanded from macro 'func'
        Args_int: func_int(param),\
                           ^~~~~
struct_args_by_val_executable.c:24:25: note: passing argument to parameter 'args' here
void func_int (Args_int args) {
                        ^
1 error generated.
```

**Why isn't my example working as expected and what is the fix here?**

On a related note, I managed to get a "pointer to a struct" version working without any issues as shown below. However, given the above compilation error, I feel as though this may have been a fluke?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct args_int Args_int;
typedef struct args_char Args_char;

void func_int(Args_int *args);
void func_char(Args_char *args);

struct args_int {
    int val;
};
struct args_char {
    char val;
};

#define func(param)\
    _Generic((param),\
        Args_int*: func_int(param),\
        Args_char*: func_char(param));


void func_int (Args_int *args) {
    printf("%d\n", args->val);
}

void func_char (Args_char *args) {
    printf("%c\n", args->val);
}

int main(void) {
    Args_char args = {0};
    args.val = 'A';
    func(&args);
}
```

The output to the above is as expected:

```
A
```

Comment: Heh that's actually not a very good code example of me that you've found there :) It's much better to include the parameter list outside the `_Generic` clause just as tstanisl just mentioned in their answer. That's how the C committee intended the feature to be used even, you can find such examples in the standard itself.

Comment: Maybe I should go edit that post, since this is (arguably) a bug. The example compiles just because `char` and `int` are implicitly convertible to each other during a function call.

Comment: @Lundin Ohhhhh I see that makes sense :) thanks for clarifying! (P.S. what a coincidence for you to see this post haha)

Comment: I might spend way too much time on this site... anyway, I edited that post now, so it doesn't cause similar trouble for anyone in the future :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that **all** expressions used in `_Generic` must be valid.
In your example macro `func` expands to:

```
int main(void) {
    Args_char args = {0};
    args.val = 'A';
    _Generic(args,
             Args_int: func_int(args),
             Args_char: func_char(args));
}
```

Note that using `func_int(args)` for `args` which is `Args_char` is causing an error.

The solution to that is using `_Generic` to select a function pointer, next apply arguments to it.

```
#define func(param)                       \
    _Generic((param),                     \
             Args_int: func_int,          \
             Args_char: func_char) (param)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this "for the record":

That's actually not a very good code example of me that you've found there! It's much better to include the parameter list outside the `_Generic` clause just as @tstanisl just mentioned in their answer (I'd accept that one as the answer to your question). That's how the C committee intended the feature to be used even, you can find such examples in the standard itself, see for example 6.5.1:

```
#define cbrt(X) _Generic((X),               \
                        long double: cbrtl, \
                        default: cbrt,      \
                        float: cbrtf        \
                        )(X)
```

The code snippet you found works by luck since `char` and `int` can be converted to each other when calling a function "as if by assignment". When using two non-compatible types that cannot get implicitly converted, the macro would expand incorrectly for the wrong type.

I've now updated https://stackoverflow.com/a/44633838/584518 to use this:

```
#define func(param)          \
  _Generic((param),          \
    int:  func_int,          \
    char: func_char)(param)  \
```